# devstack juno with nova cells enabled failing to run stack.sh with database error Unknown database 'nova_cell'

Tags: mysql, openstack, devstack, openstack-juno

```
2015-07-28 10:01:29.428 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 CRITICAL nova [-] OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'nova_cell'") None None
2015-07-28 10:01:29.428 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-07-28 10:01:29.428 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/usr/local/bin/nova-manage", line 10, in <module>
2015-07-28 10:01:29.428 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     sys.exit(main())
2015-07-28 10:01:29.428 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 1401, in main
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     ret = fn(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 902, in sync
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     return migration.db_sync(version)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/db/migration.py", line 29, in db_sync
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     return IMPL.db_sync(version=version)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/db/sqlalchemy/migration.py", line 41, in db_sync
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     current_version = db_version()
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/db/sqlalchemy/migration.py", line 53, in db_version
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     return versioning_api.db_version(get_engine(), repository)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 96, in get_engine
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     facade = _create_facade_lazily()
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/db/sqlalchemy/api.py", line 91, in _create_facade_lazily
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     _ENGINE_FACADE = db_session.EngineFacade.from_config(CONF)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/db/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 816, in from_config
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     retry_interval=conf.database.retry_interval)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/db/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 732, in __init__
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     **engine_kwargs)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/db/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 409, in create_engine
2015-07-28 10:01:29.429 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     _test_connection(engine, max_retries, retry_interval)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/db/sqlalchemy/session.py", line 549, in _test_connection
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     return exc_filters.handle_connect_error(engine)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/db/sqlalchemy/exc_filters.py", line 351, in handle_connect_error
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     handler(ctx)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/db/sqlalchemy/exc_filters.py", line 323, in handler
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     context.is_disconnect)
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo/db/sqlalchemy/exc_filters.py", line 254, in _raise_operational_errors_directly_filter
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova     raise operational_error
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'nova_cell'") None None
2015-07-28 10:01:29.430 | 2015-07-28 15:31:29.427 912 TRACE nova 
2015-07-28 10:01:29.476 | Command failed, please check log for more info
2015-07-28 10:01:29.479 | + exit_trap
2015-07-28 10:01:29.479 | + local r=1
2015-07-28 10:01:29.480 | ++ jobs -p
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | + jobs=
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | + [[ -n '' ]]
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | + kill_spinner
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | + '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | + [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | + echo 'Error on exit'
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | Error on exit
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | + [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2015-07-28 10:01:29.481 | + /home/opexlabs/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2015-07-28 10:01:29.505 | + exit 1
```

devstack juno with nova cells enabled failing to run stack.sh with database error Unknown database 'nova_cell'

I tried creating the database entries manually, but no use.

Is there any good resource for setting up devstack with nova cells ?
I tried in many places but no where its mentioned clearly.